# Design pattern for using same font accross cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, design-patterns, swift

What would be best way to unify fonts in existing app. Where I have plenty of xibs or view controllers with generated controls.

Would like to define few sizes, and one base font face.

Currently I have them defined as constants :

```
#define FONT_NAME        @"Helvetica Neue Light"
#define FONT_SIZE_NORMAL  13
....
```

But the constant are not used in xibs, and will need to go through all xibs and change fonts or have some custom code on awake from xib.

Was thinking about adding category to `NSFont`, or even swizzling `systemFontOfSize`.

Is there some design pattern to do it nicely in cocoa app ?

Comment: I think the cleanest and most "right" decision is to go with an extension.

Comment: Yeah i have now #defines and extension on NSFont. Any idea though how to go through the xibs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `NSFont` category is a good choice when you set font in code.
For xibs and storyboards I prefer using 'User Defined Runtime Attributes'. Example below is for iOS, but for MacOS it will be the same.

For example for label:
At first, create method `func fontWithStyle(style:NSNumber) -> (UIFont)` in your `UIFont` category
Then create a subclass `CustomLabel` which contains property `currentStyle`

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {
    var currentStyle:NSNumber = 0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        ...

        self.font = UIFont.fontWithStyle(self.currentStyle)
    }
}
```

And finaly, in interface builder add a runtime attribute `currentStyle` like on screenshot

[image]

Comment: I see, so i could add category to say NSLabel, and in interface builder i could set font with given size, not too bad. Guess it's better than outlets everywhere, but still bit annoying to do.

Comment: Think it is better to use NSLabel subclass instead of category, because categories can't have properties (actually can, but only using runtime 'tricks').

Comment: Thought thay may be more ways to do it but apparently there arent many. 
Accepting answer, but i used the IBOoutlets in the project for nibs instead of subclasses.

Comment: Also we can use new Xcode feature: IBInspectable property. Some information about that: goo.gl/GUvo45

Comment: can you check link, it's wrong. IBInspectable looks nice, is there min version required when using it ?

Comment: Hm, something went wrong, sorry. There is the full link: http://www.merowing.info/2014/06/behaviours-and-xcode-6/#.VFzTFIdUQo9 
This feature available in Xcode 6 and later.